# How can i get different childs from one element - Protractor

Tags: javascript, html, css, protractor

I have one element that have 20 childs:

```
test1: element(by.css('div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item:nth-child(1)')),
test2: element(by.css('div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item:nth-child(2)')),
etc etc ..... to 15
```

But i dont to place them one by one,when the only diference is the item:nth-child(...) number.
My goal is to search in all childs for one specific name, and i dont want to use if like 20 times.

Is there a way that i can connect a value inside of the "item:nth-child(value <------)" ?

I tried using :

```
test1: element(by.css('div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item:nth-child')).get(1),
```

But that didnt work

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can create a helper function that builds the search string for your loop.

```
function helperSessionItemSearch(loopRun) {
  if(loopRun<1) loopRun = 0;
  return "div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item:nth-child("+loopRun+")"
}
```

then you can creat a loop and call your new helper

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  //do something with your response...

  let response = element(by.css(helperSessionItemSearch(i)))

  //do your stuff
}
```

or use javascript templates

```
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  //do something with your response...

  let response = element(by.css(helperSessionItemSearch(`div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item:nth-child(${loopRun})`)))

  //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get text of all childs into an Array, then find the index of specific name.

```
childs = element
  .all(by.css('div.scroll-content ion-grid:nth-child(5) session-item'))

child_names = await childs.getText()

target_index = child_names.indexOf('<specific name>') // or use findIndex()
 
childs.get(target_index)
```